# How to remove $ sign and comma(s) from within parentheses

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have 1000s of lines of varying text.  Within most lines, there exists a set(s) of dollar values within parentheses.  I would like to remove the leading “$” sign and comma(s) within those parenthetical sets, so that this …

```
Ted ($633,613) blah, blah. Blah; Sue ($1,887) (Bill). John (M) ($10,927) (Art Major)
Mike ($1,200,000) blah, blah.
```

… becomes this:

```
Ted (633613) blah, blah. Blah; Sue (1887) (Bill). John (M) (10927) (Art Major)
Mike (1200000) blah, blah.
```

Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Find what: `\$(\d+),(\d+)(?:,(\d+))?`
- Replace with: `\1\2\3`
- Search mode: Regular expression

**Explanation:**

- `\$` matches the characther $
- `\d+` matches one or more digits. 1st capturing group
- `,` matches the comma
- `\d+` matches one or more digits. 2nd capturing group
- `(?:,(\d+))?` Non-capturing group that optionally matches the comma followed by one or more digits (3rd capturing group)

Comment: Fantastic!  Thanks again, Reddy!

Answer (score 1):

This will remove dollar and comma **only** within pair of parenthesis, as requested in question:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:\(|\G\d+)\K[$,](?=.*?\d\))`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:             # non capture group
    \(              # opening parenthesis
  |               # OR
    \G              # restart from last match position
    \d+             # 1 or more digits
)               # end group
\K              # reset operator, forget all we have seen until this position
[$,]            # dollar sign or comma
(?=             # positive lookahead, make sure we have after:
    .*?             # 0 or more any character, not greedy
    \d              # a digit
    \)              # closing parenthesis
)               # end lookahead
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]